# Calculations with Firebase values

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to make some easy calculation function where I can increase user's reputation, which is `String` inside Firebase. So I made it but the problem is instead of adding 1, it adds 2 and I do not see the logic error inside my code.

```
func reputationCalculation(){

        self.databaseRef.child("users").child(currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child("reputation").runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in

            var count: Int = Int(self.currentUser.generalDetails.reputation)!// At this point it is 0 in my case
            count += 1// add one to previous value
            print(count)//print the value
            self.currentUser.generalDetails.reputation = String(count)//Set the value in Singleton
            self.reputationLabel.text = self.currentUser.generalDetails.reputation//Show on label
            currentData.value = String(count)
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

        })
    }
```

For example, if the `func` is called when reputation in Firebase node is "0". It prints out `1` and `2` and sets the last value into Firebase. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the method runTransactionBlock is not called twice, it happens with firebase